# Cannot figure out how to manipulate the string

Tags: python

This code is in Python. I am in the middle of my code, and I cannot figure out how to do the step where I have find the "bub" and move everything before it with it to the end. My main problem is I can't seem to figure out how to add the parts together and put it at the end.

[Problem description]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/df8Ij.png

My code that I have done so far:

```py
def ubbi_dubbi(word):

    for i in range(len(word)):

      if(word[i] in "aeiou"):

        new_word = word[:i] + "ub" + word[i:]

        for a in range(len(new_word)):

          if(new_word in "bub"):

            new_word_bub = new_word[:a] + 

# Test cases

print(ubbi_dubbi('cat'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('up'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('upside'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('umbrella'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('tummy'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('banana'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('butter'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('hubbub'))

print(ubbi_dubbi('tube'))
```

Comment: Please don't post images that should be text

Comment: What's your actual specific question? What exact output are you seeing that makes you unhappy?

Answer (score 0):

```
flag = False
idx = -1
for i in range(len(word):
   if (i + 2 < len(word) and word[i] == 'b' and word[i+1] == 'u' and word[i+2] == 'b'):
         flag = True
         idx = i + 2
if(flag):
   new_word = word[idx+1:] + word[:idx+1]
return new_word
```

If you have questions about any part, feel free to ask but this is the big idea, i haven't tested it, but you get the idea

Comment: I am receiving errors for this code where there is an invalid syntax in the for loop, as well as a red line for flag = false statement.

Comment: As I said they're syntax errors, remove the parentheses of the for loop. capitalize the f in False and t in True. The logic should be correct. I edited the solution now

Comment: @suvi you forgot the bub rule

Comment: Please explain how I forgot it? He asked for help with the last part, I only showed the logic for that... the point  is to guide people and not do all their work for them

Answer (score 0):

```py
def ubbi_dubbi(word):
    vowels = "aeiou"
    new_word = ""
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] in vowels:
            new_word += "ub"
        new_word += word[i]
    if "bub" in new_word:
        new_word = new_word.replace("bub", "", 1)
    return new_word
```

This works perfectly for all the test cases in the example but feel free to tell me if there are any problems or have questions.